Pi4J support of 16 channel PWM / Servo Hat
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and am programming it with the brilliant Pi4J library
To implement my table tennis robot project I need:

3 brushless dc motoros for the ball firing motors.
2 servos for up / down and left / right.
1 motor for stirring the balls.
1 stepper motor for feeding the balls.

I think it is better to use hardware PWM for this, but the Raspberry Pi only supports 2 hardware pwm gpio channels.
I was therefore thinking about buying a 16-Channel PWM / Servo HAT
e.g.

https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256802290078175.html
https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi

Does Pi4J support these types of HAT and if so how?  Any example code would be really welcome.
Cheers!

you posted links that might have example code

I think they do, but it is in python, I guess I can research the library and try and convert it to java to be compatible with the Pi4j.  If there is an existing library though it would be nice to use it, help support it.
